# Can you detect when a page of a PageView is no longer visible?

Tags: flutter

I have a `PageView` full of pages that each have a scrollable list. Once I fully leave a page, I would like to scroll that list back to the top to "reset" it. One option would be to force Flutter to rebuild the page every time, but I'd prefer a more efficient option.

Comment: Rebuilding is efficient option in context of flutter.